flutter: how to prevent Scaffold drawer from being rebuilt?
flutter: how to prevent Scaffold drawer from being rebuilt?
Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(child.MyWidget),
  body: ...
);

Everytime the drawer is closed and opened, the widget tree inside the drawer will be rebuilt and all state info will be lost. For example, collapsible tab/tree node open/close states and text inputs, etc.
Tried AutomaticKeepAlive:
Scaffold(
  drawer: AutomaticKeepAlive(child: Drawer(child.MyWidget)),
  body: ...
);

class MyWidget extends StatefuleWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

    bool wantKeepAlive => true;
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       super.build(context);
       ...
    }
}


That's how the DrawerController works internally, when the animation is dismissed or the drawer is completed (hidden), the controller shows an empty widget, therefore the widget is destroyed and the next time the Widget is recreated.
You can pass the variable from your parent state to your widget or use a Provider/Bloc/etc inside your drawer:
Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(child: MyWidget(myParamsFromParentState)),
  body: ...
);


The problem is that tree node open/collapsed can not be controlled. Thanks.

DrawerController can be configured?

Is not possible :/

To prevent the Scaffold drawer from being rebuilt unnecessarily, you can use a few strategies:
Extract the Drawer as a Separate Stateful Widget
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int _counter = 0;

void _incrementCounter() {
setState(() {
  _counter++;
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Drawer Rebuild Example'),
  ),
  drawer: MyDrawer(counter: _counter),
  body: Center(
    child: Text('Counter: $_counter'),
  ),
);
}
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
final int counter;

MyDrawer({required this.counter});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      DrawerHeader(
        child: Text('Header'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Counter: $counter'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Increment Counter'),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the drawer
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}

